# Magento Undefined index: scheme in app/.../Store.php on line 1107 (Magento 1.7.0.2)

Tags: php, magento

I get the following error. It only happens once in a while and it is very hard to replicate. But when it happens, the whole page (of the live-shop) is blank and the only way to get passed it, is via restarting Memcache and Redis.

Can anyone help?

```
Notice: Undefined index: scheme  in /var/www/share/shop/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Store.php on line 1107

0 /var/www/share/shop/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Store.php(1107): mageCoreErrorHandler(8, 'Undefined index...', '/var/www/share/...', 1107, Array)
1 /var/www/share/shop/htdocs/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/switch/languages.phtml(40): Mage_Core_Model_Store->getCurrentUrl()
2 /var/www/share/shop/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/share/...')
3 /var/www/share/shop/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/base/d...')
4 /var/www/share/shop/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
5 /var/www/share/shop/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
6 /var/www/share/shop/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(582): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
7 /var/www/share/shop/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(526): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('store_language', true)
8 /var/www/share/shop/htdocs/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/html/header.phtml(41): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('store_language')
9 /var/www/share/shop/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/share/...')
10 /var/www/share/shop/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/base/d...')
11 /var/www/share/shop/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
12 /var/www/share/shop/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
13 /var/www/share/shop/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(582): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
14 /var/www/share/shop/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(526): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('header', true)
15 /var/www/share/shop/htdocs/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/2columns-right.phtml(42): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('header')
16 /var/www/share/shop/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/share/...')
17 /var/www/share/shop/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/base/d...')
18 /var/www/share/shop/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
19 /var/www/share/shop/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
20 /var/www/share/shop/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
21 /var/www/share/shop/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
22 /var/www/share/shop/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php(91): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
23 /var/www/share/shop/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Cms_IndexController->defaultNoRouteAction()
24 /var/www/share/shop/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('defaultNoRoute')
25 /var/www/share/shop/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(228): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
26 /var/www/share/shop/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
27 /var/www/share/shop/htdocs/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
28 /var/www/share/shop/htdocs/index.php(92): Mage::run('', 'store')
29 {main}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your live store shouldn't display Notice errors. Go to your root index.php and change the "error_reporting" line to this one:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be showing errors on the front-end on production. Having said that, that error seems to indicate that your virtual host is probably being accessed by IP or through a non-recognised domain by Magento, hence it's initialising the app without a store code:

```
28 /var/www/share/shop/htdocs/index.php(92): Mage::run('', 'store')
```

Note from the trace that the first parameter is empty. You should amend your setup in apache/nginx or the index.php, to make sure that the store code always fallbacks to a default value (not empty). That should get rid of the error.

Answer (score 0):

A usual cause of the issue are not quite correct demo data of a design theme installed.
To fix the issue run the following SQL command:

`UPDATE core_config_data 
SET value = 'http://example.com/' 
WHERE path IN ('web/secure/base_url', 'web/unsecure/base_url');`

Place your site root URL instead of `http://example.com/`.
Then delete the cache.